# Form Submission Sends an Unwanted GET Request

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to use an HTML form to submit data to my Spring/Thymeleaf server.  When I use the POST method to submit, a second request is sent with the same URL but with an additional "?error" query parameter and a GET method.  This subsequent request causes errors since it does not carry the information that was present in the body of the POST request and I am required to handle this second request somehow.  In my inspector window it says that the second request was initiated by the first request somehow.

Upon changing the method to GET, the request works perfectly.  This solution doesn't work for me, though, because I am using the form to submit password data.

Here is the form that is causing problems (classes etc. omitted):

```html
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span><i></i></span>
        </div>
        <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span><i></i></span>
        </div>
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${_csrf.token}" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}">
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="button">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the controller that handles all requests to /login (this isn't finished yet, but it's possible I'm missing something essential here) :

```java
@Controller()
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doGet() {
        System.out.println("Login page accessed");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doPost() {
        System.out.println("Login attempted");
        return "redirect:home";
    }
}
```

Expected output when submitting the form is "Login Attempted", but the only result is "Login Page Accessed".

Here's the security configuration method which explicitly defines some extra functionality for this endpoint

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/about", "/login", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/assets/**" ).permitAll()        
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
            .csrf()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .addLogoutHandler( new CookieClearingLogoutHandler() );
    }
```

The first request seems to not even reach the controller.  How can I avoid the second request being sent?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your form. It should only be sending the one POST. There is no way that this could be sending a GET. The problem must be somewhere else in your code. Is there another form on the same page? Do you have any JavaScript that is run when submit is clicked? Does your server have any other hooks that respond to a POST?

Comment: There is no other form in the HTML document, and no javascript either.  Some other hooks respond to POSTs so I'll experiment a bit to see if those are being hit somehow.

Comment: Upon poking around a bit more it seems like only the GET endpoint in the same LoginController is being triggered.  Somehow the POST is being blocked before it can even arrive at the server?

Comment: It is possible that your server has a setting to ignore the request, or it could be rerouting it to another endpoint. Do you have any more code you can post? Or can you provide more information about your server setup?

Comment: I've added/updated some data to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra `/login?error` call is initiated by Spring Security whenever a login failure occurs.  This is the default form login `authenticationFailureUrl`.

Spring Security has a default `/login` POST handler, and your code is likely conflicting with it (i.e., your form post data goes to Spring Security's handler instead of yours, then failing authentication there and causing the redirect to error).

You might want to check out `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and `CustomAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I fixed the issue by renaming my "/login" GET handler to just "/" and letting Spring handle the POSTs as outlined in the SecurityConfiguration file.